# How to align menu item text in Actionbar overflow menu

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm using ActionBarSherlock to implement an actionbar in my Android application. Menu options that don't fit on this actionbar are automatically added to the overflow menu.
The problem I'm facing is that these menu options have center alignment:

[image]

How do I make sure that the menu items in the overflow menu are right-aligned, like for example in the Gmail application?

Thanks.

Comment: "The problem I'm facing is that these menu options have center alignment" -- you might consider posting a screenshot, details about the environment (device? OS version?), and whatever customizations to the action bar you may have made in an Android theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind, I found the cause.

It turns out I was styling TextView somewhere in my theme with

```
<item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
```

and this also affected the menu items.