# Overflow menu items text align to center

Tags: android, android-actionbar, overflow-menu

I have an action-bar with an overflow menu.
In that overflow menu i have text in each item.
currently the items are align to left. 
And i want them to align to center in the overflow menu through XML.

Below there is my themes.xml - in "myCustomMenuTextApearance" style i used the "gravity" attribute but it didn't work.
When i moved the "gravity" attribute to "MyAppActionBarTheme" style it worked the items were centered but also all the rest of the TextView i have in my Activity layout.
Which isn't what i wanted at all.

I found these links but didn't found any help there:
1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22702588/align-items-inside-of-a-menu-coming-from-actionbar

[How to align menu item text in Actionbar overflow menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14759897/how-to-align-menu-item-text-in-actionbar-overflow-menu)

[Align Center Menu Item text in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19344297/align-center-menu-item-text-in-android)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<style name="MyAppActionBarTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle" tools:targetApi="11">@style/MyApp.PopupMenu</item>
    <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/myCustomMenuTextApearance</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle" tools:targetApi="11">@style/MyApp.ActionBar</item>

</style>

<!-- The beef: background color for Action Bar overflow menu -->
<style name="MyApp.PopupMenu" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/ab_menu_bkg</item>

</style>

<style name="myCustomMenuTextApearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TextView.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
</style>

<!-- Bonus: if you want to style whole Action Bar, not just the menu -->
<style name="MyApp.ActionBar" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid">

    <!-- Blue background color & black bottom border -->
    <item name="android:background">@color/red</item>
</style>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried setting <item name="android:width">-1dp</item> on myCustomMenuTextApearance ?

Comment: yes just did, but it didn't help.

Comment: Did you find solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can center-align the menu items dynamically using SpannableString in your activity:

`int positionOfMenuItem = 0; //or any other postion

MenuItem item = menu.getItem(positionOfMenuItem);

SpannableString s = new SpannableString(settingsItemTitle);

s.setSpan(new AlignmentSpan.Standard(Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER), 0, s.length(), 0);

item.setTitle(s);`